# How do we visualize csv point cloud data?

Tags: python, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am having an xyz file I want to preprocess and save it as a df, how do I visualize the csv file or convert it into xyz or las format in python

Comment: What about `df = pandas.read_csv()`? Have you looked into pandas, geopandas.
It is not clear what you mean by "visualize", what is Ias, and so on.

Comment: xyz is a point cloud data format, I have point cloud points data in csv file and I want to convert it into 3D format to visualize using open3d

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70598949/reading-pointcloud-from-csv-to-ros-pointcloud2) help? You would need  to use your point cloud format instead of 
 `sensor_msgs`

Answer (score 0):

save each xyz to a line, separate by a space, and add a column represent the color, and save these lines to a txt file, then open the file with cloud-compare.

the txt file will looks like:

```
1.23 0.12 3.45 1
2.23 1.12 4.45 1
3.23 2.12 5.45 0
```